# Remote deployment of jbpm-project from external repository

Tags: jbpm, kie, kie-workbench

Have an external repository, that is an standalone application on the same VM, where is jbpm installed. Can deploy kjar from it to kie-workbench clicking New Deployment Unit, but would like to make it programmatically. What approache can you suggest? I've found two possibilities, one with kie-config-cli.sh, but unfortunately it doesn't seems work, the second with Rest Api with /maven/deploy command, but for this purpose it should be already created project on the kie-server, that's why I would like to avoid this one. 
1. Regarding first approach: I am using kie-config.cli to 'add-deployment', enter all the same version, groupId and organisation, as I do it manually in kie-workbench itself, but nothing appears in kieworkbench (yes, settings.xml is aware about my external repository).

Thank you in advance!

Jbpm 6.4.0.Final at Wildfly 8.2.0, Apache Archiva 2.2.1 at Jetty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is there already a rest-api for this purpose:
POST@  /rest/deployments/groupId:artifactId:version/deploy
BODY:
Header: Content-Type: application/xml

*settings.xml (maven) on the local machine, where it is to deploy, should be aware about your external repository as well as pom.xml should contain this information (and it will, if you deploy to it with 'mvn deploy')!

Answer (score 1):

The KIE Server allows for full lifecycle of it.

> the second with Rest Api with /maven/deploy command, but for this purpose it should be already created project on the kie-server, that's why I would like to avoid this one.

If by "project" you mean "container", then use the HTTP PUT method to create the container: 
http://(server)/(context)/services/rest/server/containers/(containerName)

With an XML request something like:

```
<kie-container container-id="(containerName)">
  <release-id>
    <group-id>com.myCompany.productName</group-id>
    <artifact-id>product-name-module-name</artifact-id> 
    <version>1.0</version> 
  </release-id> 
</kie-container>
```

Comment: Hello Jeff, will it automatically create a project in kie-workbench, as it would be made manually and save it in local maven repository (on the server) as well as deploying? I believe, I've found a better solution as I 've asked the same question on jbpm-usage email-listing . And it was exactly what I've meant by this (without creating an redundant project in maven, while it has already created by external repository): we can use as httprequest: /rest/deployment/<groupdId:artifactId:version>/deploy and in BODY should be added empty <deployment-descriptor/>. That's it! And thank you!

Comment: Right, so by "project" you meant the ruleset, and KIE Server has the Maven lifecycle endpoints too.